# Android : Automatically remove unused images from project bundle

Tags: android, image, bundle

I am developing an android project that is pretty big and have many images in drawable folder. Many of these images are not being used in the project (because they have been replaced) and they consume valuable space. Is there any way that I could automatically find those images and delete them, instead of searching through each image in the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tools I have used are

[android unused resources](https://code.google.com/p/android-unused-resources/)

and

[android lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint)

One of the features does say

> Unused resources

Comment: That won't find unused image resources, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

We open sources a tool that removes all unused resources automatically from your project based on android lint output.
Even unused strings and other 'inline' resources.

https://github.com/KeepSafe/android-resource-remover

Answer (score 0):

Now we can do it automatically with gradle

```
 buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled true
                shrinkResources true
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
```

More details are here
https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-shrinking