# check whether image is used or not in a project

Tags: java, android

i am new to android. In the project most of the images are used, for some reason some of the images are not used.
But all the images are present in the res/drawable's folder. Going through the code to find which images are not used is a time consuming.
How could i check which images had not used anywhere in the project and remove it.
Solution with reference link could be better.

Comment: remove the one by one image from drawable if projects show error then that image is used

Comment: there are more than thousands of images. removing and checking the error one by one is a time consuming task. How could be done done faster

Comment: A similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17715780/android-automatically-remove-unused-images-from-project-bundle?rq=1

Comment: I tried using lint and also AndroidUnusedResources.jar file also but its not identifying the unused images. Is there any tool which automatically delete the unused resources from the project ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Eclipse` you can run `Lint Error Checking` to know which files are used and which ones aren't.

Go to Window->Preferences->Android->Lint Error Checking

If you do any change in the list of enabled checks and click Apply you will be asked if you want to run `lint`. Click Yes and all the files that you aren't using will be marked with a warning.

Answer (score 1):

Android Lint will do this for you. Check out [Lint Tool](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) - I guess, it otherwise depends on which IDE you're using. I know that IntelliJ will mark unused items in the main R.java file itself. But afaik, Eclipse doesn't do this.

Best bet is to use Lint. You can run it from command line also, so doesn't matter what IDE you're using.